# Do I need to match the ESR for the components on this schematic and how?

Tags: voltage-regulator, switching-regulator, esr, passive-components

I'm using this schematic given to me by the TI power designer tools and the passive components all have ESRs attached to them. Do I need to make sure my components have these ESRs to get the desired voltage output, or can I just ignore them? If I do, how do I make sure that I can get these?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The proposed components will work. The Power Designer tool does not give you any information whether other components will work.

The datasheet tells you what characteristics you need.
In the case of the TPS563200, it says:

> The proprietary D-CAP2 control scheme supports low ESR output capacitors such as specialty polymer capacitors and multi-layer ceramic capacitors without complex external compensation circuits.
> [...]
> An internal ramp is added to reference voltage to simulate output ripple, eliminating the need for ESR induced output ripple from D-CAP2 control scheme.

In other words, there are no ESR requirements.

Other devices might have ESR requirements, but the only way to find out is to read the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

> *Do I need to make sure my components have these ESRs to get the
> desired voltage output, or can I just ignore them? If I do, how do I
> make sure that I can get these?*

- Modify the ESRs and **see how the tool responds**
- Find a range of ESR values that allow an improved chance of picking a real component
- Note the ripple voltage changes with ESR; make sure this doesn't grow too big
- Use and abuse the **TI power designer tool** until you get a usefule result